# Repeat background with clip?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have this background that I'm using for a section, and it starts with a small arrow engraving at the top:

[image]

However I'm trying to get it when it repeats to clip out the top arrow part, just leaving the texture in the middle part. I was wondering if it was possible to do it with something like webkit? Thanks

Comment: why not just create another image?

Comment: Dear show the code/ fiddle that will be very helpful to understand your problem more quickly for all viewers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to come up with another method of doing so. There are a number of ways to do this. Personally, I would use only the arrow, but use inner box-shadow for the shadows on everything else. This way you have smaller image being used, and it will always fit the size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Break up the background image from the pointer and make the two separate sprites.  You can get tricky with the pointer and have it point in all 4 directions in the same image.  This will allow you to pop up the bubble in all directions from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat both x and y on a usable sprite.

I have a maximum of three sprites in my projects.

One for non-repeating elements, another for repeat-x, another for repeat-y.

I find the `clip` property pretty much useless.